# LINQ Composite Key GroupJoin with keys unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, linq, join, composite-key, linq-group

I'm trying to get a GroupJoin to work with multiple unknown keys using LINQ.

I've seen solutions with anonymous types, but the keys were always pre-defined.
In my case, they're user-defined, so I wouldn't know that information at compile time. I tried to use a list of key values and an array of key values, but they never match.

So... this works like a charm:

```
Func<Component, string> getKeyValue = x => x.Attributes                            //from attributes
                                            .Single(a => a.Name == _keyAttribute) //selects the key attribute
                                            .Value;                              //gets attribute value

var leftJoin = source.GroupJoin(target,                  //join
                                getKeyValue,            //on the same
                                getKeyValue,           //condition
                                (src, corresp) => new
                                {
                                   src,
                                   corresp
                                })
                    .SelectMany(z => z.corresp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                              .Select(tgt => new { z.src, tgt })) //selects matching
                    .ToList();                                                   //source and target
```

but this doesn't:

```
Func<Component, List<string>> getKeyValues = x => x.Attributes                 //from attributes
                                 .Where(a => _keyAttributes.Contains(a.Name)) //selects key attributes
                                 .OrderBy(a => a.Name)                       //order them by name
                                 .Select(a => a.Value)                      //gets attributes' values
                                 .ToList();
var leftJoin = source.GroupJoin(target,                  //join
                                getKeyValues,           //on the same
                                getKeyValues,          //condition
                                (src, corresp) => new
                                {
                                   src,
                                   corresp
                                })
                    .SelectMany(z => z.corresp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                              .Select(tgt => new { z.src, tgt })) //selects matching
                    .ToList();                                                   //source and target
```

If it helps, this is the structure I'm working on:

```
List<string> _keyAttributes;
List<Component> source;
List<Component> target;

[DataContract]
public class Component
{
   [DataMember]
   public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }

   public Component()
   {
      new List<Attribute>();
   }
}

[DataContract]
public class Attribute
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to solve this using LINQ library or I'd need my own GroupJoin extension method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the getKeyValues selector you provide will return a `List` from each `Component` to compare on. The returned `List` from each will be compared by *reference*, so essentially you've got this going on:

```
var listA = new List<string> { "SomeString" };
var listB = new List<string> { "SomeString" };

bool areListsEqual = listA == listB;
```

`areListsEqual` will return false, since they are compared by reference. Essentially what you'll need is either a different `EqualityComparer` (available to add via an overload of `GroupJoin`), or you need a way to compare the properties by *value*.

An example of something that would work (but not necessarily a good way to do it) would be:

```
Func<Component, string> getKeyValues = x =>
    string.Join(",", x.Attributes
                      .Where(a => _keyAttributes.Contains(a.Name))
                      .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
                      .Select(a => a.Value).ToArray());
```

This will create a string that represents the values in each list, and that will be used for comparison. A better way would be to use an `EqualityComparer` that has your own logic for what makes the lists actually equal based on the values contained within. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815387/compare-two-lists-c-sharp-linq) for how you might compare two lists.

Comment: Haven't thought of joining values. Since they're all string, that works. I agree with you that it's not necessarily a good way to do it, but I think it will do. Not with a comma, but with an unique combination of characters.
Thank you!

Comment: Thinking better, I will stay with the solution of implementing an EqualityComparer for List<T> or T[] and passing it as an extra argument to GroupJoin.

Comment: IEqualityComparer was the way to go! Thank you!